# Page Loading Query

Tags: php, jquery, overlay, loading

is it possible to display an overlay before my php page does anything else, then continue loading the page.

Once the page is fully loaded, then remove the overlay ?

Ideally the overlay should have an icon and/or wording showing the page is loading.

Everything I have tried doesn't seem to do anything !

Thanks

**EDIT:**

This is basic version of what I'm trying to do..

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Blocks as soon as possible
    $.blockUI({ message: $('#domMessage') });

    // Wire up page load event
    $(window).load(function () {
        // Unblock when page is loaded
        $.unblockUI;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$out = array();
exec ('ls -ls /* 2>&1', $out);
echo "<table>";
foreach ($out as $line) {
    echo "<tr><td>$line</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>

<input id="pageDemo1" class="demo" type="submit" value="Block Page With Message" />
<div id="domMessage" style="display:none;">
    <h1>We are processing your request.  Please be patient.</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The page loads then shows the overlay message.

How do I get it to show the message while loading ?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly have you tried that did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery BlockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) has worked very well for me in the past.

You can apply it to elements or the entire page, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    // unblock when ajax activity stops 
    $(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI); 

    function test() { 
        $.ajax({ url: 'wait.php', cache: false }); 
    } 

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#pageDemo1').click(function() { 
            $.blockUI({ message: $('#domMessage') }); 
            test(); 
        });
    }); 
</script> 

<input id="pageDemo1" class="demo" type="submit" value="Block Page With Message" />
<div id="domMessage" style="display:none;"> 
    <h1>We are processing your request.  Please be patient.</h1> 
</div>
```

Note: The `DIV` with `id="domMessage` is being passed to the `blockUI` function and is used to display the message.

UPDATE:

Here is how you can show the loading message as soon as the DOM is available and then hide the message when the page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // Blocks as soon as possible
    $.blockUI({ message: $('#domMessage') });

    // Wire up page load event
    $(window).load(function () {
        // Unblock when page is loaded 
        $.unblockUI; 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Great option. Yet this part I don't understand `$.ajax({ url: 'wait.php', cache: false });` about the `wait.php` file. Can you tell me what that file is used for? I read the documentation but can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Oh that is just the example from the jQuery BlockUI site, it is merely a delay in a PHP script so that the overlay shows in the examples. Feel free to take out the `function test()` part and the call to it (`test()`) and put whatever you want to happen inside your event handler.

Comment: I wasn't the one who asked the question Karl, but I will be happy to vote up. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- - LOL, sorry my fault, need to pay closer attention to the names, just figured you were the OP.

Comment: Hahaha not a problem, it happens to the best of us ;-) I browse questions to see if I can help and it happens sometimes that I see a good question with an answer that could be of use to me down the road. Gave you `+1`

Comment: Thanks for this, but how do I get it to block straight away with out the user having to click anything ? Then when the page is loaded unblock ?

Comment: @user1932360 - see `UPDATE:` in answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The page loads then the message is displayed and doesn't go away. It's as if my page is loading first..

Comment: @user1932360 - put an alert in `$(window).load(function () {` and see if/when the event is happening.

Comment: Added an alert as suggested. The page fully loads, the alert is shown and when cleared the loader is shown !

Comment: anyone any ideas on this ? why does it load after my page is loading ? Thanks